# generate rows with numbers between ranges on Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with the columns:

```
range_start BIGINT
range_end   BIGINT
```

What I'm looking for is a new table that contains every integer between the specified ranges:

```
range_start,
range_start+1
range_start+2
.
.
range_end
```

The total range will be in the order of a few billion rows, so I'm looking for an efficient solution :)

It seems that `EXPAND ON` is only for dates, but I couldn't get a hold of the official documentation, so not really sure about that (in general, the lack of easily retrievable documentation is a real problem with TD)

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: "A few billion rows"

 is quite a lot, `EXPAND ON` only works with date/time, but could be tweaked (probably). `CROSS JOINs` or a number table might be better, what is this used for and how often do you need to run it?

All Teradata documentation is avaliable at http://www.info.teradata.com.

I prefer the full manuals on CD, but it's also online, you need to look at http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_151K/ch01.021.194.html

Comment: This is used to expand ranges of IPs for basically the whole world. Regarding the documentation, I'm very sorry but you guys are way, way behind the curve here. It takes me ~1 second to find the appropriate documentation for anything on python, c++, scala, you name it, by simply googling it.  With TD, it's a struggle. Just my 2 cents here but it's *very* frustrating for a lot of us.

Comment: Why do you need to expand all IPs? What if you need IPv6?

Comment: How would you increment an ip address octet that ends in 255 without code?

Comment: Additionally, how can you possibly have billions of ip addresses? That's an awful lot of computers/nics.

Comment: @dnoeth. I would like to have a fast look up lat/lon for any IP that may come up. Since TD is really fast at joining for well distributed primary indices, this lookup would be really fast over the expanded ranges. We happen to have one of the biggest TD clusters around, so billions is generally quite OK

Comment: @Andrew, the octets ranges are converted to a numeric variable prior to the expansion, so then it's a simple integer expansion

Comment: @Andew: billions is not that many. we are after all billions of human beings. That doesn't mean that all the IPs need to be realized, but I have no way of knowing which ones don't.